# Как сделать структуру блоков как на картинке?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Нужно таблицу из блоков как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть какие нибудь идеи?

Вот через флекс пробовал, не работает как хотелось бы

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  max-width: 490px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.wrap {
  margin: 0 -3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrap::after {
  content: '';
  flex: auto;
}

.item {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 3% 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Выхотите что бы это сделали вместо вас? Где ваш код в котором вы пытались это сделать?

Comment: flex, grid, float. куча идей

Comment: @E_K я хотел добавить но мне выдает ошибка `Ссылки на jsfiddle.net должны сопровождаться кодом`

Comment: @E_K Вот через флекс пробовал, не работает как хотелось бы [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jzn1s5o/22/)

Comment: Можно вставить код прямо в вопрос, без всякого jsfiddle. Нажмите "редактировать", а помто CTRL+M (или кнопку в тулбаре - в средней группе самая правая, "Фрагмент кода на...".

Answer (score 0):

Допустим... ) Принцип понятен?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {}

.item {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  float: left;
  margin-right: calc((100% - 4 * 85px) / 3);
  margin-bottom: calc((100% - 4 * 85px) / 3);
}

.item:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .item {
    margin-right: calc((100% - 3 * 85px) / 2);
    margin-bottom: calc((100% - 3 * 85px) / 2);
  }
  .item:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: calc((100% - 3 * 85px) / 2);
  }
  .item:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```